# Using a BY variable in coxph( ) or survreg( )

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

I've got the output of some simulations that look something like this:

```
Run,ID,Time,Var1,Outcome
1,1,6,0.5,1
1,2,4,0.25,1
1,3,2,0.9,1
2,1,5,0.07,1
...
10,3,9,0.08,1
```

Basically a series of M studies of N individuals (in actuality M = 1000 and N = 123). I'd like to run a Cox model (preferably) or a parametric regression model (if I must) to estimate the effect of `Var1` on survival time. What I want to do is estimate the effect for each "Run" (to produce 1,000 estimates) and then dump all those estimates into a single data frame, matrix, etc. where I can look at their distribution.

If I were using SAS, the code would look something like this:

```
ods output ParameterEstimates=work.parameters;
proc phreg model time*outcome(0) = Var1;
   BY Run;
run;
ods output close;
```

But since this is a side project, and I'm trying to force myself to do side projects in R in order to learn it, I can't so much fall back on SAS. As far as I can tell from the coxph() documentation, there's no easy way to include a by-variable. My guess is this is going to involve loops and subsets.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're after (this may be due to my ignorance with time series) but replicate may be what you're after.

Comment: I would suggest using `plyr::ddply` or `data.table` as opposed to a loop or subset.

Comment: @TylerRinker The same question could apply to something like lm(). Essentially, how take a data set and apply something like lm() on levels of that variable.

Comment: @EpiGrad then mnel's reponse is good as would the use of base's `split` and then `lapply`.  You'd then have to grab the pices from lapplying the cox model and use `do.call` to put them back together as a dataframe.

Comment: There's `nlme::lmList` to be used for `lm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using `plyr` or data.table

```
## some data
set.seed(123)
.data <- data.frame(run = rep(1:10, each = 50), x = runif(500))
.data$y <- .data$x * rep(runif(10),each = 50)

# ---------------------------------------------------------
# using plyr
library(plyr)
# ddply to extract just the coefficients
ddply(.data, .(run), function(data) data.frame(coef = coef(lm(y ~ x, data))))
    # or save the whole object
# the whole lm object 
lm_list <- dlply(.data, .(run), lm, formula = y ~ x)
# get the coefficients    
ldply(lm_list, coef)
# print the summaries
llply(lm_list, summary)

# ---------------------------------------------------------
# with data.table 
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(.data)
setkeyv(DT, 'run')

DT[, list(coef = coef(lm(y~x, .SD))), by = 'run']
```